# Optimize the rearranging of bits

Tags: c#, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a core C# function that I am trying to speed up. Suggestions involving safe or unsafe code are equally welcome. Here is the method:

```
public byte[] Interleave(uint[] vector)
{
    var byteVector = new byte[BytesNeeded + 1]; // Extra byte needed when creating a BigInteger, for sign bit.
    foreach (var idx in PrecomputedIndices)
    {
        var bit = (byte)(((vector[idx.iFromUintVector] >> idx.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << idx.iToByteBit);
        byteVector[idx.iToByteVector] |= bit;
    }
    return byteVector;
}
```

`PrecomputedIndices` is an array of the following class:

```
class Indices
{
    public readonly int iFromUintVector;
    public readonly int iFromUintBit;
    public readonly int iToByteVector;
    public readonly int iToByteBit;

    public Indices(int fromUintVector, int fromUintBit, int toByteVector, int toByteBit)
    {
        iFromUintVector = fromUintVector;
        iFromUintBit = fromUintBit;
        iToByteVector = toByteVector;
        iToByteBit = toByteBit;
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `Interleave` method is to copy bits from an array of uints to an array of bytes. I have pre-computed the source and target array index and the source and target bit number and stored them in the Indices objects. No two adjacent bits in the source will be adjacent in the target, so that rules out certain optimizations.

To give you an idea of scale, the problem I am working on has about 4,200 dimensions, so "vector" has 4,200 elements. The values in vector range from zero to twelve, so I only need to use four bits to store their values in the byte array, thus I need 4,200 x 4 = 16,800 bits of data, or 2,100 bytes of output per vector. This method will be called millions of times. It consumes approximately a third of the time in the larger procedure I need to optimize.

**UPDATE 1:** Changing "Indices" to a struct and shrinking a few of the datatypes so that the object was just eight bytes (an int, a short, and two bytes) reduced the percentage of execution time from 35% to 30%.

Comment: Since `Indices` is a small, immutable type have you tried making it a `struct`?

Comment: is `PrecomputedIndices` an array or `List`?

Comment: If you sort the indices by either input or output index, you can halve the size of that thing and also make access of one of them linear. Also if it's an interleave in the usual sense (perfect shuffle) then you don't need any indexes.

Comment: * PrecomputedIndices is an array, not a List.   * I considered making Indices a struct. That would give it value semantics, which would mean the foreach loop would make copies of the struct. That seems to give and take at the same time, so not sure which is faster.  * The permutation is constant for one instance of the transformation of points. (All points have their bits permuted in the same way.) However, the program is a solver that will try thousands of permutations, looking for an optimal solution of a problem. Each permutation is randomly generated.

Comment: You could make it an array of ints (perhaps smaller) to avoid struct copying

Comment: @PaulChernoch making it a struct will give the elements cache locality, the compiler may handle the copying cleverly, best thing is to try it.

Comment: @Harold - It is a sort of round-robin thing. I take the highest important bit from one dimension, then the highest bit from a second, etc until done. Then I move on to the second highest bit of each dimension, taking the dimensions in the same order (an order that was initially randomly generated.)

Comment: since you call this millions of times use `for` loop instead of `foreach`. it will save a very short time. but better than nothing.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - Good point. I am not clever about things related to cache locality. Did lots of C programming in the eighties, but C# has spoiled me and ruined my good habits.

Comment: Then why not just keep the order of the dimensions? You already know the rest of the order, and it's trivial to generate on the fly. Also there is a really nice optimization there: you can build one `uint` at the time (gathering the bits) without it going back and forth through memory (and you can poke it into the byte array directly with `unsafe`)

Comment: @Harold - yes I can sort PrecomputedIndices array so as to ensure that I build bytes in an increasing sequence or read them in an increasing sequence (not sure which is best, but I can only do one). I was ready to give up. You all have such good ideas. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

These are the crucial parts of my revised implementation, with ideas drawn from the commenters:

1. Convert object to struct, shrink data types to smaller ints, and rearrange so that the object should fit into a 64-bit value, which is better for a 64-bit machine:

   ```
   struct Indices
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Index into source vector of source uint to read.
       /// </summary>
       public readonly int iFromUintVector;
       /// <summary>
       /// Index into target vector of target byte to write.
       /// </summary>
       public readonly short iToByteVector;
       /// <summary>
       /// Index into source uint of source bit to read.
       /// </summary>
       public readonly byte iFromUintBit;
       /// <summary>
       /// Index into target byte of target bit to write.
       /// </summary>
       public readonly byte iToByteBit;
       public Indices(int fromUintVector, byte fromUintBit, short toByteVector, byte toByteBit)
       {
           iFromUintVector = fromUintVector;
           iFromUintBit = fromUintBit;
           iToByteVector = toByteVector;
           iToByteBit = toByteBit;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Sort the PrecomputedIndices so that I write each target byte and bit in ascending order, which improves memory cache access:

   ```
   Comparison<Indices> sortByTargetByteAndBit = (a, b) =>
   {
       if (a.iToByteVector < b.iToByteVector) return -1;
       if (a.iToByteVector > b.iToByteVector) return 1;
       if (a.iToByteBit < b.iToByteBit) return -1;
       if (a.iToByteBit > b.iToByteBit) return 1;
       return 0;
   };
   Array.Sort(PrecomputedIndices, sortByTargetByteAndBit);
   ```
3. Unroll the loop so that a whole target byte is assembled at once, reducing the number of times I access the target array:

   ```
   public byte[] Interleave(uint[] vector)
   {
       var byteVector = new byte[BytesNeeded + 1]; // An extra byte is needed to hold the extra bits and a sign bit for the BigInteger.
       var extraBits = Bits - BytesNeeded << 3;
       int iIndex = 0;
       var iByte = 0;
       for (; iByte < BytesNeeded; iByte++)
       {
           // Unroll the loop so we compute the bits for a whole byte at a time.
           uint bits = 0;
           var idx0 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex];
           var idx1 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 1];
           var idx2 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 2];
           var idx3 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 3];
           var idx4 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 4];
           var idx5 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 5];
           var idx6 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 6];
           var idx7 = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex + 7];
           bits = (((vector[idx0.iFromUintVector] >> idx0.iFromUintBit) & 1U))
                | (((vector[idx1.iFromUintVector] >> idx1.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 1)
                | (((vector[idx2.iFromUintVector] >> idx2.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 2)
                | (((vector[idx3.iFromUintVector] >> idx3.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 3)
                | (((vector[idx4.iFromUintVector] >> idx4.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 4)
                | (((vector[idx5.iFromUintVector] >> idx5.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 5)
                | (((vector[idx6.iFromUintVector] >> idx6.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 6)
                | (((vector[idx7.iFromUintVector] >> idx7.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << 7);
           byteVector[iByte] = (Byte)bits;
           iIndex += 8;
       }
       for (; iIndex < PrecomputedIndices.Length; iIndex++)
       {
           var idx = PrecomputedIndices[iIndex];
           var bit = (byte)(((vector[idx.iFromUintVector] >> idx.iFromUintBit) & 1U) << idx.iToByteBit);
           byteVector[idx.iToByteVector] |= bit;
       }
       return byteVector;
   }
   ```

- #1 cuts the function from taking up 35% of the execution time to 30% of the execution time (14% savings).
- #2 did not speed the function up, but made #3 possible.
- #3 cuts the function from 30% of exec time to 19.6%, another 33% in savings.

**Total savings: 44%!!!**

Comment: You're confining the reordering to bytes? Why not just create a 256-byte array of translated values, and then just index into it? If you're translating lots of bytes, it will fly after you've generated the table.

Comment: Typical case: Array X[4000] integers have their bits rearranged. The first output byte gets one bit from X[0], one bit from X[1], one from X[2], etc. That is the interleaving process. I do not think a lookup table will work. If it could, I would be interested.

Comment: Another idea: unpack the input data into a byte array, one LSB bit per byte. Then use your index array to copy them, with random access, to a second byte array. Then pack the second array into the output array. With some unrolling, the unpack and pack loops should get your bitwise operations done with minimal cycles.